# How to add a button to questionnaire

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make a button that is light in color and unclickable until a user answers all 3 questions and when that happens the button lights up and is clickable. The button generates the links that are already within the code and it takes them to the desired page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<script>
function tryToMakeLink()
{
    //get all selected radios
    var q1=document.querySelector('input[name="q1"]:checked');
    var q2=document.querySelector('input[name="q2"]:checked');
    var q3=document.querySelector('input[name="q3"]:checked');
    //make sure the user has selected all 3
    if (q1==null || q2==null ||q3==null)
    {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="--";
    }
    else
    {
        //now we know we have 3 radios, so get their values
        q1=q1.value;
        q2=q2.value;
        q3=q3.value;
        //now check the values to display a different link for the desired     
configuration
        if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>att 8gb black</a>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Other" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>other 8b 
white</a>";
        }
        else if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>another     
option</a>";
        }
        else if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>oops</a>";
        }
        else if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>can't</a>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Other" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>yours</a>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Other" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>mines</a>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Other" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>what</a>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>red</a>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>orange</a>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>green</a>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>blue</a>";
        }
    }
}
</script>

<form name="quiz" id='quiz'>

What carrier do you have?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
    <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" value="AT&T"/>AT&T</li>
    <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1"  
value="Other"/>Other</li>
    <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" 
value="Unlocked"/>Unlocked</li>
</ul>

What is your phones capicity?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
    <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q2" value="8GB"/>8GB</li>
    <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q2" value="16GB"/>16GB</li>
</ul>

What color is your phone?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
    <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q3" 
value="Black"/>Black</li>
    <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q3" 
value="White"/>White</li>
</ul>

<br>
<div id=linkDiv>
 ---
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekcKW/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some errors in your code related to [IF..ELSE statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

`if (q1==null || q2==null ||q3==null)`  and  `if ((q1=="AT&T" ) && ( q2=="8GB" ) && ( q3=="Black"))`

should be :

`if ((q1==null) || (q2==null) ||(q3==null))` and  `if ((q1=="AT&T" ) && ( q2=="8GB" ) && ( q3=="Black"))`.

I added a button with `id='btn'` and has `disabled` attribute so that it can't be clicked.

We add this part to your js code to check if button should be enabled or not.Button will show your linkDiv(hidden by default) once clicked.

```
   var button=document.getElementById('btn');
   button.removeAttribute('disabled');
   button.onclick=function() {
                 document.getElementById("linkDiv").setAttribute('style','display:block;');
                };
```

DEMO HERE : http://jsfiddle.net/Ct8BF/

Comment: Your a life saver. Do you think that you could help me with 1 more thing pertaining to this code?

Comment: Ok well I've tried over 15 solutions and they don't work at all. Is there anyway you can maybe help me replace the radio buttons with images. I've been referred many times but none of them work. You seem like you know the solution.

Comment: what kind of images ? do you want to stylish radio or replacing them with images?clarify please?

Comment: No not stylish buttons. I just want each radio button replaced with custom images.

Comment: after click on button , because if you replace radio,images can't be selected anymore!!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36201/discussion-between-user2680614-and-faceofjock)

Comment: images would act as a radio button.